# z-index causing rendering issues in webkit based browsers

Tags: css, plugins, webkit, rendering, z-index

I've got this plugin as an animated background http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/ and my website page structure is the same as example 3.

I've set the background to be fixed, with a z-index of -100 which stops the footer from blending with the background (since I want it to be a solid colour).

For some reason I get this bizarre rendering issue which only happens when z-index is active. I have a fixed navbar that animates to black and shrinks when you scroll down. When I scroll it gets stuck, when I scroll up it leaves a clipping of the navbar in place from where it just was.

[image: Clipping in webkit browsers]

Does anyone else have any experience with this? And possibly some insight into why this is happening? As far as I am aware it's only a z-index issue with chrome and opera.

The less that sets the background in place (and the z-index call)

```
#ri-grid {
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

I tried to fix it with -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100); which I found on a chrome bug site, but it didn't work :'(

Any help is much appreciated! x

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, although I have absolutely NO idea why it caused that weird error to happen.

I just nested the background element into a div with a class of grid-bg and set the z-index on that instead. Makes no sense, but it worked.

```
.grid-bg {
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(100);
}

#ri-grid {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```